# Create Sequences by Group ID using numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have written a function to get a sequence for LSTM/GRU sequence model based on group ID. I am not getting expected output.

Python Function:

```
def windowGeneratorByID(data, target, id_col_index, lookback, offset, batch_size=16):
  min_index=0
  max_index = data.shape[0]-offset
  i = min_index + lookback
  while 1:
    if i + batch_size >= max_index:
      i = min_index + lookback
    rows = np.arange(i, min(i + batch_size, max_index))
    i += len(rows)
    samples = np.zeros((len(rows), lookback, data.shape[-1]))
    targets = np.zeros((len(rows), target.shape[-1]))

    for j, row in enumerate(rows):
      indices = range(rows[j] - lookback, rows[j])
      if data[rows[j] + offset][id_col_index] in set(data[indices][:, id_col_index]):
        if len(set(data[indices][:, id_col_index])) == 1:
            samples[j] = data[indices]
            targets[j] = target[rows[j] + offset]

    yield  np.delete(samples,id_col_index,axis=2) , targets
```

**Input:**

```
df=np.array([[1,1,0.1,11],[1,2,0.2,12], [1,3,0.3,13], [1,4,0.4,14], [2,5,0.5,15], [2,6,0.6,16], [2,7,0.7,17],[3,8,0.8,18],[3,9,0.9,19],[3,10,0.7,20]])
```

**Output Code:**

```
lookback=2
batch_size=2
offset = 0
windows = windowGeneratorByID(data=df, target=df[:,2:4],id_col_index=0 , offset=offset, lookback=lookback,batch_size=batch_size)

#The number of total batches are equal to the number of (training examples - lookback-offset)/batch_size 
no_batches=int((df.shape[0]-lookback-offset)/batch_size)

# #print the batches
for i in range(no_batches):
  #get the next batch from the windowGenerator
  input,output=next(windows)
  print("{}th batch: \ninput is:\n{}\n and \ntarget is:\n{}\n".format(i+1, input, output))
```

**Expected Output:**

```
1th batch: 
input is:
[[[ 1.   0.1 11. ]
  [ 2.   0.2 12. ]]

 [[ 2.   0.2 12. ]
  [ 3.   0.3 13. ]]]
 and 
target is:
[[ 0.3 13. ]
 [ 0.4 14. ]]

2nd batch: 
input is:
[[[ 5.   0.5 15. ]
  [ 6.   0.6 16. ]]

 [[[ 8.   0.8 18. ]
  [ 9.   0.9 19. ]]
 and 
target is:
[[ 0.7 17. ]
 [ 0.7 20. ]]
```

Comment: Why the second target is: `[[ 0.7 17. ] [ 0.7 20. ]]` ?

Comment: Also, do explain how the function parameters operate. What is the use of offset, lookback id_col_index etc. That way people are able to find new solutions for this from scratch.

Comment: Do check my updated answer. I provide a simpler generator method as well as a vectorized NumPy method for your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two methods that will get you what you are trying to solve. One is a **generator method** like yours to get 1 batch at a time, and the second is a **vectorized NumPy method** that operates on the complete data at once to get all the batches (This method can be used on chunks of df instead of complete).

**Generator method**

1. A `chunk`, with `offset` and `lookback`, is basically a single set of rows X to y. So if I want `lookback 2`, `offset 1`. Then I need 4 rows from df. The first 2 will go to X and the last one will go to y. Similarly, if I need `lookback 1` `offset 0`, then I need just 2 rows. First goes to X and last goes to y.
2. With this understanding, I can calculate the max number of chunks I can get from each group with rolling windows and store it in `c`
3. Once I have this, I simply need to create a function that lets me rolling iterate over the rows of df, selecting the number of chunks and then skipping a few since those few will have elements from different groups. So, if I have `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]` and I have `c = [2,1,1]` and skip (aka `lookback+offset`) = 1. Then I have to take 2, skip 1, take 1, skip 1, take 1, skip 1. So, `[0,1,3,5]`, is what I would iterate. And I would take the size of chunk starting from each of these indexes.
4. Next it's super simple. Just get a generator setup that pulls these chunks and for a `batch size = n`, pulls n chunks and stacks them before returning.

```
df=np.array([[1,1,0.1,11],
             [1,2,0.2,12], 
             [1,3,0.3,13], 
             [1,4,0.4,14], 
             [2,5,0.5,15], 
             [2,6,0.6,16], 
             [2,7,0.7,17],
             [3,8,0.8,18],
             [3,9,0.9,19],
             [3,10,0.7,20]])

def take(xs, runs, skip_size):
    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65163947/iterate-over-a-list-based-on-list-with-set-of-iteration-steps'
    ixs = iter(xs)
    for run_size in runs:
        for _ in range(run_size ):
            yield next(ixs)
        for _ in range(skip_size):
            next(ixs)
            
def get_batch(df, target, lookback, offset, batch_size):
    _ , c = np.unique(df[:,0], return_counts=True)
    rows = (lookback+offset+1)
    w = c-rows+1
    itr = take(range(len(df)), w, lookback+offset)
    while 1:
        X, Y = [],[]
        for _ in range(batch_size):
            k = next(itr, 'out of batches!')
            x = df[k:lookback+k, 1:]
            y = df[rows+k-1:rows+k, target]
            X.append(x)
            Y.append(y)
        try: yield np.stack(X), np.stack(Y)
        except: break
            
            
lookback = 2
offset = 0
batch_size = 2
target = slice(2,4) #set the target as a slice instead of a separate df view

windows = get_batch(df, target, lookback, offset, batch_size)

no_batches = int(np.sum(np.unique(df[:,0], return_counts=True)[1] - lookback - offset)/batch_size)

for i in range(no_batches):
    input,output=next(windows)
    print("{}th batch: \ninput is:\n{}\n and \ntarget is:\n{}\n".format(i+1, input, output))
```

```
#Lookback = 2, offset = 0, batch_size = 2 

1th batch: 
input is:
[[[ 1.   0.1 11. ]
  [ 2.   0.2 12. ]]

 [[ 2.   0.2 12. ]
  [ 3.   0.3 13. ]]]
 and 
target is:
[[[ 0.3 13. ]]

 [[ 0.4 14. ]]]

2th batch: 
input is:
[[[ 5.   0.5 15. ]
  [ 6.   0.6 16. ]]

 [[ 8.   0.8 18. ]
  [ 9.   0.9 19. ]]]
 and 
target is:
[[[ 0.7 17. ]]
```

Another example -

```
lookback = 1
offset = 1
batch_size = 1
target = slice(2,4) #set the target as a slice instead of a separate df view

windows = get_batch(df, target, lookback, offset, batch_size)

no_batches = int(np.sum(np.unique(df[:,0], return_counts=True)[1] - lookback - offset)/batch_size)

for i in range(no_batches):
    input,output=next(windows)
    print("{}th batch: \ninput is:\n{}\n and \ntarget is:\n{}\n".format(i+1, input, output))
```

```
#Lookback = 1, offset = 1, batch_size = 1

1th batch: 
input is:
[[[ 1.   0.1 11. ]]]
 and 
target is:
[[[ 0.3 13. ]]]

2th batch: 
input is:
[[[ 2.   0.2 12. ]]]
 and 
target is:
[[[ 0.4 14. ]]]

3th batch: 
input is:
[[[ 5.   0.5 15. ]]]
 and 
target is:
[[[ 0.7 17. ]]]

4th batch: 
input is:
[[[ 8.   0.8 18. ]]]
 and 
target is:
[[[ 0.7 20. ]]]
```

---

**Vectorized NumPy method**

If however, you are ok to use a vectorized NumPy compute over all of the data at once, instead of the generator method, I have written the following as well. *If df is massive, then you can simply pass chunks of df to this function and get a set of batches for that chunk.*

1. Break array into unequal length groups based on id_column
2. Get rolling windows over axis=0 using stride tricks
3. Stack all the windows into a block
4. Calculate the number of batches possible
5. Keep only the number of blocks that can successfully be stacked into equal-sized batches
6. Split block by num batches and get X
7. Split block by num batches and get y
8. Return all the X, y as batches in a single array

```
df=np.array([[1,1,0.1,11],
             [1,2,0.2,12], 
             [1,3,0.3,13], 
             [1,4,0.4,14], 
             [2,5,0.5,15], 
             [2,6,0.6,16], 
             [2,7,0.7,17],
             [3,8,0.8,18],
             [3,9,0.9,19],
             [3,10,0.7,20]])

lookback=1
batch_size=2
offset = 1

def window_split_2d(g, window):
    shp = (g.shape[0] - window + 1, window, g.shape[-1])
    strd = (g.strides[0], g.strides[0], g.strides[1])
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(g, shape=shp, strides=strd)

def get_batches_vectorized(df, target, id_col_index, lookback, offset, batch_size):

    #Break array into unequal length groups based on id_column
    groups = np.split(df, np.where(np.diff(df[:,id_col_index]))[0]+1)
    
    #Get rolling windows over axis=0 using stride tricks
    chunks = [window_split_2d(i,lookback+offset+1) for i in groups]
    
    #Stack all the windows into a block
    block = np.vstack(chunks)
    
    #Calculate number of batches possible
    n_batches = block.shape[0]//batch_size
    
    #Keep only the number of blocks that can successfully be stacked into equal sized batches
    keep = block.shape[0]-(block.shape[0]%batch_size)
    block = block[:keep]
    
    #Split block by num batches and get X
    X = np.split(block[:,:lookback,1:], n_batches)

    #Split block by num batches and get y
    y = np.split(block[:,-1,target], n_batches)
    return X, y
```