# Iterate over a list based on list with set of iteration steps

Tags: python

I want to iterate a given list based on a variable number of iterations stored in another list and a constant number of skips stored in as an integer.

Let's say I have 3 things -

1. `l` - a list that I need to iterate on (or filter)
2. `w` - a list that tells me how many items to iterate before taking a break
3. `k` - an integer that tells me how many elements to skip between each set of iterations.

To rephrase, w tells how many iterations to take, and after each set of iterations, k tells how many elements to skip.

So, if w = [4,3,1] and k = 2. Then on a given list (of length 14), I want to iterate the first 4 elements, then skip 2, then next 3 elements, then skip 2, then next 1 element, then skip 2.

Another example,

```
#Lets say this is my original list

l = [6,2,2,5,2,5,1,7,9,4]
w = [2,2,1,1]
k = 1
```

Based on w and k, I want to iterate as -

```
6 -> Keep # w says keep 2 elements 
2 -> Keep
2 -> Skip # k says skip 1
5 -> Keep # w says keep 2 elements
2 -> Keep
5 -> Skip # k says skip 1
1 -> Keep # w says keep 1 element
7 -> Skip # k says skip 1
9 -> Keep # w says keep 1 element
4 -> Skip # k says skip 1
```

I tried finding something from itertools, numpy, a combination of nested loops, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around how to even iterate over this. Apologies for not providing any attempt, but I don't know where to start.

I dont necessarily need a full solution, just a few hints/suggestions would do.

Comment: Use a generator.  Iterate over 'w`, and each iteration should grab some elements from `l` (and yield them), and then skip over `k` elements.  Does that help?

Comment: @Grismar I think my idea was posted pretty much simultaneously with the answer.  And I actually did what he wanted and gave him a hint, rather than solving it.

Comment: Fair cop, removing my comment.

Comment: What's up with the terrible names? Why `w` and `k` instead of for example `take` and `skip`? Trying to make your question and answers harder to understand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works:

```
l = [6,2,2,5,2,5,1,7,9,4]
w = [2,2,1,1]
k = 1

def take(xs, runs, skip_size):
    ixs = iter(xs)
    for run_size in runs:
        for _ in range(run_size ):
            yield next(ixs)
        for _ in range(skip_size):
            next(ixs)

result = list(take(l, w, k))
print(result)
```

Result:

```
[6, 2, 5, 2, 1, 9]
```

The function is what's called a generator, yielding one part of the result at a time, which is why it's combined into a list with `list(take(l, w, k))`.

Inside the function, the list `xs` that is passed in is wrapped in an iterator, to be able to take one item at a time with `next()`.

`runs` defines how many items to take and yield, `skip_size` defines how many items to skip to skip after each 'run'.

As a bonus, here's a fun one-liner - if you can figure out why it works, I think you know enough about the problem to move on :)

```
[y for i, y in zip([x for xs in [[1] * aw + [0] * k for aw in w] for x in xs], l) if i]
```

Comment: Nice. I was going to suggest a shorter implementation, but I like how you did it.

Comment: The one-liner actually has an advantage: It doesn't crash if `l` is "too short".

Comment: @superbrain that's a good observation, although depending on how you would use something like this, failing silently might be considered worse than (correctly) throwing a `StopIteration` exception. Anyone using a routine like `take` should catch that exception if it can occur (and the docstring of the routine should make it clear that this exception is likely to be thrown).

Comment: Hmm... I can somewhat agree, but only if `l` is too short for `w`, not for `k`. The latter's specification says *"skip **between** each set of iterations"*, and if I pop `l`'s `4`, then your main solution still crashes because it tries to skipread **after** the last set. Btw, I can never skip an opportunity to use my favorite not-well-known itertool :-): `[*compress(l, [x for xs in [[1] * aw + [0] * k for aw in w] for x in xs])]`

Answer (score 4):

[@Grismar's implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65163978/2988730) is excellent: straightforward, legible, and maintainable. Here is the compressed illegible version of the same:

```
from itertools import islice
from collections import deque

def take(xs, runs, skip_size):
    ixs = iter(xs)
    for run_size in runs:
        yield from islice(ixs, run_size)
        deque(islice(ixs, skip_size), maxlen=0)
```

The behavior is nearly identical in both cases.

**v2**

Based on [@superb rain's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65173438/2988730) fastest proposal, here is a slightly tweaked solution:

```
def take(xs, runs, skip_size):
    ixs = iter(xs)
    irs = iter(runs)
    yield from islice(ixs, next(irs, 0))
    for run in irs:
        yield from islice(ixs, skip_size, run + skip_size)
```

Comment: Behavoir is *not* identical. Yours doesn't crash if the list is "too short". It's also not illegible. You even wrote `maxlen=` even though you don't have to. I think it's just as straightforward as Grismar's.

Comment: @superbrain. Thanks. I hadn't noticed about the crash. That actually makes this objectively better. It's not really illegible, but some of the idioms are a bit obscure to the beginner (like emptying an iterator using a deque).

Comment: Meh, I often use deque like that :-). Mostly for benchmarking as it's the most efficient iterator consumer I know. Like I did in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65173438/13008439) now.

Comment: I disagree that it makes it objectively better, although the difference in behaviour is certainly important. I'd want to know if I'm not getting what I expect (even if that's due to bad input), instead of the function failing silently and returning a result that doesn't match expected post conditions. I think both solutions are elegant, depending on what you're going for - I was going for something that's explicit and easy to read for someone who is learning. I'd probably use @MadPhysicist's solution with a check on the inputs if that was needed, or catch the `StopIteration`.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a simple for loop and keep track of the current index where your range starts. Then in each iteration just update the start based on the previous one and your value of `k`.

```
l = [6,2,2,5,2,5,1,7,9,4]
w = [2,2,1,1]
k = 1

def get_slices(l, w, k):
    start = 0
    for n in w:
        yield from l[start: start+n]
        start += n + k
        

list(get_slices(l, w, k))
# [6, 2, 5, 2, 1, 9]
```

If you are using python > 3.8 you can stretch the readability a bit in exchange for brevity and fun with the walrus operator:

```
l = [6,2,2,5,2,5,1,7,9,4]
w = [2,2,1,1]
k = 1

start = -k

g = (slice(start:=start + k, start:=start + n) for n in w)
[j for slice in g for j in l[slice] ]
# [6, 2, 5, 2, 1, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [Mad Physicist's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65164082/13008439) but using `islice` with start and stop argument:

```
def take(xs, runs, skip_size):
    ixs = iter(xs)
    start = 0
    for run in runs:
        yield from islice(ixs, start, start + run)
        start = skip_size
```

A little benchmark with similar solutions:

```
2.63 μs  2.39 μs  2.29 μs  Grismar
2.11 μs  2.12 μs  2.11 μs  Mad_Physicist
1.49 μs  1.45 μs  1.35 μs  Mark_Meyer
1.34 μs  1.37 μs  1.38 μs  superb_rain
1.37 μs  1.40 μs  1.35 μs  superb_rain_2
1.34 μs  1.43 μs  1.35 μs  Mad_Physicist_2
```

Code:

```
from timeit import repeat
from itertools import islice
from collections import deque

def Grismar(xs, runs, skip):
    ixs = iter(xs)
    for run in runs:
        for _ in range(run ):
            yield next(ixs)
        for _ in range(skip):
            next(ixs)

def Mad_Physicist(xs, runs, skip):
    ixs = iter(xs)
    for run in runs:
        yield from islice(ixs, run)
        deque(islice(ixs, skip), 0)

def Mark_Meyer(xs, runs, skip):
    start = 0
    for run in runs:
        yield from xs[start : start+run]
        start += run + skip
        
def superb_rain(xs, runs, skip):
    ixs = iter(xs)
    start = 0
    for run in runs:
        yield from islice(ixs, start, start + run)
        start = skip

def superb_rain_2(xs, runs, skip):
    ixs = iter(xs)
    iruns = iter(runs)
    for run in iruns:
        yield from islice(ixs, run)
        for run in iruns:
            yield from islice(ixs, skip, skip + run)

def Mad_Physicist_2(xs, runs, skip):
    ixs = iter(xs)
    iruns = iter(runs)
    yield from islice(ixs, next(iruns, 0))
    for run in iruns:
        yield from islice(ixs, skip, run + skip)

funcs = Grismar, Mad_Physicist, Mark_Meyer, superb_rain, superb_rain_2, Mad_Physicist_2

l = [6,2,2,5,2,5,1,7,9,4]
w = [2,2,1,1]
k = 1
expect = [6, 2, 5, 2, 1, 9]
number = 10**5

for func in funcs:
    print(list(func(l, w, k)) == expect, func.__name__)
print()

tss = [[] for _ in funcs]
for _ in range(4):
    for func, ts in zip(funcs, tss):
        t = min(repeat(lambda: deque(func(l, w, k), 0), number=number)) / number
        ts.append(t)
        print(*('%.2f μs ' % (1e6 * t) for t in ts[1:]), func.__name__)
    print()
```

Comment: Did you check all the outputs against each other?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Half-manually, yes. You can see my benchmark code actually also prints the outputs, and the output is the same `6 2 5 2 1 9` for all four functions. Why do you ask? Do you see an issue?

Comment: I don't see an issue. Just checking. I added another version based on your second one. Basically removed the nested loop since you only use the outer loop to call `next` once

Comment: @MadPhysicist Included your new version now (after fixing the empty-ixs issue and renaming irs to iruns, as I'm keeping the variable names the same for code length comparison, wouldn't have used the annoying `_size` suffixes in mine otherwise :-). I guess I'm just too much in love with the trick of using `for` only for the first element. In the use case where I originally came up with that, it was better than using `next` (both code length and speed), but not here.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. I'm on mobile right now. About to fix my answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I got:

```
l = [6,2,2,5,2,5,1,7,9,4]
w = [2,2,1,1]
k = 1
testList = []
pos = 0

for wItem in w:
    for i in range(wItem):
        testList.append(l[pos+i])
    pos += k + wItem
l = testList
```

test list will be a temporary list you store items in until the loop is completely executed.

I use the variable pos to keep track of the position you have looped to in the function and then ad the amount you want to skip after each iteration of the inner loop.